# Sorting Number in Custom Header Ag-Grid?

Tags: angular, sorting, ag-grid

Does Ag-grid column api have information about sorting order number in custom header component ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this plunk: [ag-grid: Custom Header component - get sort order](https://plnkr.co/edit/S5a3tD?p=preview)

You can get it using `IHeaderParams` within `CustomHeaderComponent`.

Sort the columns `Age` and then `Year` keeping <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed. You could see the sorting is being done, the array or columns are being loogged in the console with the appropriate order.

```
onSortChanged() {
  console.log(this.params.api.sortController.getColumnsWithSortingOrdered());
}
```

Now you can add your logic to set the appropriate sort order in your custom header component.

Comment: Hi, @paritosh thank you for your help. I have resolved this issue and create plunker with an example.

Comment: I'm getting a Typescript error: Property 'sortController' is private and only accessible within class 'GridApi'

Comment: @HDog use `(this.params.api as any).sortController.getColumnsWithSortingOrdered()`

Comment: @Paritosh please see [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59670533/213050) which is using public Api and type checking.

Answer (score 1):

We must attach the event listener to the grid api's `sortChange` event, rather than the column api's.  That's because the sortNumber could change based on a click of a different column.  You can see [comment to that effect in sourcode of HeaderComp](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/9565c219b6210aa85fa833c929d0728f9d163a91/community-modules/core/src/ts/headerRendering/header/headerComp.ts#L257).  In the example below, an event stream is created using rxjs `fromEvent` of grid api `sortChange` which is piped to my custom computation of this column's sortNumber.

This solution uses the available public API of ag-grid with type checking. In current Api we should not use `sort` and `sortedAt` which are private properties of Column, but we have `getSort()` and `getSortedAt()`.  Although `getSortedAt()` does not appear in [the documentation of GridColumn](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column/) we can see it if we inspect directly [the typings of `Column`](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/9565c219b6210aa85fa833c929d0728f9d163a91/community-modules/core/typings/entities/column.d.ts)

```js
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { IHeaderAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { AgGridEvent, Column, IHeaderParams } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { Subject , fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-datagrid-header-cell',
  templateUrl: './datagrid-header-cell.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datagrid-header-cell.component.scss']
})
export class DatagridHeaderCellComponent implements IHeaderAngularComp, OnDestroy {
    protected destroyed$ = new Subject<void>();
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroyed$.next();
    }
    public params: IHeaderParams;
    public sortNumber = 0;
    public showSortNumber = false;

    agInit(params: IHeaderParams): void {
        this.params = params;

        fromEvent(this.params.api, 'sortChanged').pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroyed$),
            tap((e: AgGridEvent) => this.setMultiSortOrder(e))
        ).subscribe();
    }

    private setMultiSortOrder(e: AgGridEvent) {
        if (!e || !e.columnApi) return;
        let sortedColumns = (e.columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns() || [])
            .filter((col: Column) => col.getSort())
            .sort((a,b) => a.getSortedAt() - b.getSortedAt());

        this.sortNumber = sortedColumns.findIndex(col => col === this.params.column) + 1;
        this.showSortNumber = this.sortNumber > 0 && sortedColumns.length > 1;
    }
  }
```

And finally, this is how we can invoke the sortNumber display from the markup:

```html
<span ref="eSortOrder"
  class="ag-header-icon ag-sort-order"
  *ngIf="showSortNumber">{{sortNumber}}</span>
```

Ag-grid documentation references:

1. [Ag Grid Events - see *SortChangedEvent*](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#properties-and-hierarchy)
2. [Grid Column Api - see *getAllDisplayedColumns()*](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/)
3. [Grid Column - see *getSort()*](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column/)
4. [Grid Column Properties - see *sort* and *sortedAt*](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue using plain js.
It can be useful to someone. 
Please check to example plunk here : [Angular 2 sorting order ag-grid](https://plnkr.co/edit/14N5IT?p=preview)
I am using this method to gain sorting numbers and add them to DOM:

```
checkSortOrder() {
const sortingArray = this.params.api.getSortModel();
let j: number;
if (sortingArray.length > 1) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    for (j = 0; j < sortingArray.length; j++) {
      this.sortNumber = j + 1;
      const sortingDom = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('sortingOrder' + sortingArray[j].colId.replace(/\s/g, ''))
      sortingDom.innerHTML = this.sortNumber.toString();
    }
  });
}
```

}